# How to deal with Turtle's shield

Tags: dirty-bomb

A new merc, Turtle, got recently added to the game. He has a deployable shield that blocks enemy damage, but lets allies shoot through it.

Since the merc is new, it's being used in just about every match by at least one player. So I'm having to deal with his shield a lot.

How do I deal with the shield? Escpecially at long range when it's blocking something like the objective point or a chokepont?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main weakness of Turtle's shield are explosives, like Nader, Javelin, etc. The shield has a bullet damage modifier (0.9), but I think explosives can do full damage to it (can't confirm this). Desconsidering explosives, Rhino it's the best merc to take down the shield quickly, he has a very high DPS, and his low accuracy it's not a problem since shield's hitbox is large.